# Restricting a ScrollView to scroll only when a specific button is pressed in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a scrollView in my app and I have 9 buttons on each I want when the last button (9th button) is tapped only then the scrollView scrolls else it shouldn't even scroll. Where should I apply the checks from the below methods:

```
1.scrollViewDidScroll
2.scrollViewWillBeginDragging
3.scrollViewDidEndDecelerating
```

Or if you can tell any other way to do that?

Comment: Do you want it to scroll when the 9th button is touched, or only after you've touched all nine buttons? If the latter, do the touches have to occur in a particular order?

Comment: @rdelmar, on the 9th button.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to check any of the delegate methods, just set scrollingEnabled to No, initially, and set it to YES in the 9th button method .